# "Failed to instantiate one or more class" in layout preview of idea

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea

My project can build and run correctly,but I can't preview all layout of it.I have tried Invalidate caches and restart but it's useless.
idea version is 2018.3
All layout preview has this error:

> Failed to instantiate one or more class
>       The following classes could not be instantiated:
>       - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>       - android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>        Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected
>   error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the
>   layout.
>       Exception Details
>       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener Copy stack to clipboard

AppTheme Style
I have change Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar to Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar,but it's useless:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout</item>
    <item name="bottomNavigationStyle">@style/Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView</item>
</style>
```

gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ijkm1.linlingo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}    
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
        implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
        implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.17'
        implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.17'
        implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.17'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
        implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2"
        implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0"
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
        implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'


        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
        annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.17'
        annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.17'

}
```